# Access individual bits in a char c++

Tags: c++, bit

How would i go about accessing the individual bits inside a c++ type,  `char` or any c++ other type for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c)

Comment: Theoretically not a duplicate (C vs C++) but similar enough to close this one.

Comment: Yes i did see the C version but i wanted to know how to do this in C++ since i see its the same i guess you can close it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you want access bit `N`:

Get: `(INPUT >> N) & 1;`

Set: `INPUT |= 1 << N;`

Unset: `INPUT &= ~(1 << N);`

Toggle: `INPUT ^= 1 << N;`

Comment: one should always emphasize what bit N is. In this case here we have bit 0 as the right most and least significant bit. 
There are other notations out there, who do this differently.

Comment: @CarstenGreiner, In general, we can assume that anything is zero based in programming. It is a standard that is obeyed by most, if not all, collections.

Comment: @Mat : I am working a lot with hardware and their respective register definitions. And you see registers being defined as having 0 to 63 - where 0 is the left most bit. And I see also registers being defined as 63 to 0. Concerning collections, element 0 is the first one - I do not disagree.

Comment: @CarstenGreiner, When I say "start" I should possibly have been more clear. I mean the right-most bit, or least significant bit, is zero. That is something that I have always found to be consistent as a definition for most common applications. Adjusting the code to account for an alternative definition of `N` should be easy though.

Comment: Can any body explain me how Toggle works from above ? I undrstand that N is the bit we are targeting and 1 << N shifts the bits of 1  by N times placing the 1 at Nth postion

Comment: @aash20 - `^=` is the eXclusive OR (XOR) operator, which sets the bit if exactly one of the input bits is set. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Truth_table) for the truth table.

Answer (score 7):

You would use the binary operators `|` (or), `&` (and) and `^` (xor) to set them. To set the third bit of variable `a`, you would type, for instance:

```cpp
a = a | 0x4

// c++ 14
a = a | 0b0100
```

Note that 4’s binary representation is 0100

Answer (score 1):

That is very easy
Lets say you need to access individual bits of an integer
Create a mask like this
int mask =1;
now, anding your numberwith this mask gives the value set at the zeroth bit
in order to access the bit set at ith position (indexes start from zero) , just and with (mask<

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look at the nth bit in a number you can use: `number&(1<<n)`.

Essentially the the `(1<<n)` which is basically `2^n(because you shift the 1 bit in ...0001 n times, each left shift means multiply by 2)` creates a number which happens to be `0` everywhere but `1` at the nth position(this is how math works).

You then `&` that with `number`. This returns a number which is either `0` everywhere or a number that has a `1` somewhere(essentially an integer which is either 0 or not).

Example:
`2nd` bit in in 4, `4&(1<<2)`

```
  0100
& 0010
  ____
  0000 = 0
```

Therefore the `2nd` bit in 4 is a 0

It will also work with chars because they are also numbers in C,C++