# Confused with Union in C

Tags: c, unions

I could not understand how Union works..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    union {
    int a:4;
    char b[4];
    }abc;
abc.a = 0xF;

    printf(" %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", sizeof(abc), abc.a, abc.b[0], abc.b[1], abc.b[2], abc.b[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]
     In the above program.
I made `int a : 4;`
So, a should taking 4 bits.
now I am storing, `a = 0xF; //i.e a= 1111(Binary form)`
So when I am accessing `b[0 0r 1 or 2 or 3]`                                                   why the outputs are not coming like `1, 1, 1, 1`

Comment: Actually, accessing `abc.b` after you assigned to `abc.a` is undefined behaviour, as far as I know. You shouldn't rely on it in any way you might think it would work.

Comment: @NiklasB. No longer if C11 is available, it's defined there.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Good to now, thanks.

Comment: @OP: I think you are confusing bits with bytes.

Comment: @Daniel: Is it also defined how it plays together with bitfields?

Comment: @NiklasB: Finally I got the answer. When I am declaring i = F;

Comment: @NiklasB. The standard says "If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation." So you get whatever bits happened to sit where you read. I think the value bits of the bit-field must be the first bits of the memory location, everything else is up to the implementation.

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think bit-fields have to use any particular bits of the underlying integer type first. Not sure what you mean by "first bits": within a byte there are only most- and least-signficant bits, neither is "first". But whichever you mean, I don't think the implementation is required to use them preferentially :-)

Comment: @Steve You're right, I thought wrong. Got confused by the requirement that the next bitfield be stored in the same unit of storage if there is sufficient space or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your union's total size will be at least `4 * sizeof(char)`.

Assuming the compiler you are using handles this as defined behavior, consider the following:

1. `abc` is never fully initialized, so it contains a random assortment of zeros and ones. Big problem. So, do this first:
    `memset(&abc, 0, sizeof(abc));`
2. The union should be the size of its largest member, so you should now have 4 zeroed-out **bytes**: `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`
3. You are only setting 4 **bits** high, so your union will become something like this:
   `00000000 00000000 00000000 00001111`   or 
   `11110000 00000000 00000000 00000000`. 
   I'm not sure how your compiler handles this type of alignment, so this is the best I can do.

You might also consider doing a char-to-bits conversion so you can manually inspect the value of each and every bit in binary format:
[Access individual bits in a char c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531214/access-individual-bits-in-a-char-c)

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

0xF is -1 if you look at it as a 4-bit signed, so the output is normal. b is not even assigned fully, so it's value is undefined. It's a 4 byte entity but you only assign a 4-bit entity. So everything looks normal to me.

Answer (score 0):

Because every `char` takes (on most platforms) 1 byte i.e. 8 bits, so all the 4 bits of `a` fall into a single element of `b[]`.

And beside that, it is compiler-dependent how the bit fields are stored, so it is not defined, into which byte of `b[]` that maps...

Answer (score 0):

0xF is -1 if you defined it to be a 4 bit signed number. Check [two-complement binary representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to understand why.

And you didn't initialize `b`, so it could be holding any random value.