# How to use bits for control statement expression?

Tags: c++

I'm using the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9531250) answer to get and set bit values of a `char`. The setting and getting has no/shouldn't have any problem (semantically the same as the linked answer).

Problem is I can't properly use the bit values from it in control statements (`if`).

The relevant piece of code in which I'm having the problem:

```
unsigned long int find_container(unsigned long int k){
  return (k)/(sizeof(char)*8);
}

unsigned long int find_bit(unsigned long int k){
  return (k)%(sizeof(char)*8);
}

....
if (~(marks[find_container((k-3)/2)] >> (find_bit((k-3)/2)&1))){
  printf("must print\n");
}
marks[find_container((k-3)/2)] |= 1<<find_bit((k-3)/2);
  
if (~(marks[find_container((k-3)/2)] >> (find_bit((k-3)/2)&1))){
  printf("this shouldn't have been printed\n");
}
....
```

Prints:

> must print
>
> this shouldn't have been printed

It's evident that the `if` statement doesn't take bit value expressions.

Well, I tried casting the bit value to `bool` (`~(bool)((marks[find_container((k-3)/2)] >> (find_bit((k-3)/2)&1))`) but it didn't change this behavior.

Initially all the value in the `marks` array is set to zero

```
marks = (char *)calloc( chars, (sizeof(char)));
```

`chars` is an `unsigned long int`

So how can I have if statements uses bit expressions?

Comment: I recommend you put the whole `((k-3)/2)/(sizeof(char)*8)` expression in a function or a macro, then it might be easier to see what you're doing, as well as it should be easier to both read and write the code. The expression can be somewhat simplified too, as `sizeof(char)` is specified to return `1`, always.

Comment: That code is... remarkable. Are you writing C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: Why not just use `std::bitset` instead of this code that makes my eyes bleed?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have to use a variable length array that's why I had to quit `bitset`

Comment: @BleedingFingers Well, `vector<bool>` could have been used.  Or even `boost::dynamic_bitset`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `vector<bool>` has a large memory footprint. And the array can be very large. `dynamic_bitset` isn't native, I believe that's why didn't use it.

Comment: @BleedingFingers At this stage, the boost libraries are practically native.  Many or most of their classes make it into the standard.

Comment: `vector<bool>` does _not_ have a large memory footprint (which leads to other issues that _are_ good reasons not to use it)

Comment: @BleedingFingers: Please don't tag C++ questions C. Of course it makes a difference to what solutions are available. They are different languages.

Comment: @BleedingFingers - Well it's your choice.  Either use classes and/or libraries that are tested, work, and used by thousands of programmers and companies all over the world, or keep trudging away with home-made code that may or may not work, have hidden bugs, etc.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is redundant - it's 1 by definition.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg done to a certain extent.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie g++ and mpic++ doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(find_bit((k-3)/2)&1)
```

is either 0 or 1.

I think you misplaced your parentheses and that you're looking for

```
(marks[find_container((k-3)/2)] >> find_bit((k-3)/2)) & 1
```

I would recommend that you add abstracting functions for manipulating bits, it makes the code much more readable and less error-prone.
Something like this.

```
// No safety, for clarity
void set(unsigned long int* bits, size_t which)
{
   bits[find_container(which)] |= 1 << find_bit(which);
}

bool get(unsigned long int* bits, size_t which)
{
   return (bits[find_container(which)] >> find_bit(which)) & 1;
}

// example
if (!get(marks, k))
{
    set(marks, k);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, you can use any value in an if and values not equal to zero are considered true.

But how you can tell what all that code is doing is beyond me. The chances of that having a bug are high.

I'd suggest writing some individual functions to read/clear/set a particular bit in your array. Then it should become clearer what you are doing.

Incidentally, if this is c code, you shouldn't be casting the result of calloc. If on the other hand, it is C++ code, you shouldn't be using C-style casts.